# new array with two objects with values from two objects with same key javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

been trying for a while something i want to do:

i have two  different objects with same keyName and different values, i need to create a new array that will contain a new object with two entries, the values from the two objects with same key.

```
enter code here
OBJ1{ keyNAME : 'lalala', toto: 'bbbb', tata: 'blablabla' }

OBJ2{ keyNAME : 18, toto: 7, tata: null }

// here something that i imagine could look similar to:
    
let newObjectKeys =  ['title', 'value' ] 
    
function createMyNewArray()=> {

     let newArray = []
     Use somehow OBJ1 and OBJ2, check the keys and create new array using 
     newObjectKeys
     i think it might use Object.keys method but all i have tried i don't get to the 
     result i need so i'm defo missing something 
} 


return newArray; 

console.log("new Array", newArray)
```

OUTPUT WOULD LOOK LIKE:

```
const newArray =[
   {
     string: "lalala",
     value: 18
   },
   {
     string: 'bbbb', 
     value: 7, 
   },
   {
     string: 'blablabla'
     value: null
   }, 
   
   ....
   ];
```

and so then i can use it on my front side like this:

```
{newArray.map((item)=> return(
<div>
p {item.string}
p {item.value}
</div>

))}
```

thank you

Comment: what is supposed to happen if OBJ2 does not have the respective property from OBJ1. Like what if OBJ1 has {foo: 1} and OBJ2 does not have "foo" at all.

Comment: I just noticed you are returning "newArray" outside the scope of the function, it will ALWAYS be undefined.

Comment: Hi @Smytt, thanks for your answer and questions, about the first one, i know there will be the same keys as i have the return from my API in postman and i use this keys to create my first array with the strings, the only thing could happens is my second array gives me a key with value null if there's no number, 

About the return i might have putted my return outside trying to recreate my example, but yes should be inside.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: okay , sorry @Yunnosch

Comment: Everybody is learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
OBJ1 = { key: 'lalala', toto: 'bbbb', tata: 'blablabla' }

OBJ2 = { key: 18, toto: 7, tata: null }

const createArray = (obj1, obj2) =>
  Object.keys(obj1).map(key => ({
    string: obj1[key],
    value: obj2[key]
  }))

console.log(createArray(OBJ1, OBJ2))
```

Is this what you seek to do? Since you know for sure that both your objects are built with the same properties, we can create an array with the properties only - with Object.keys(). Then, we can traverse the array with the "map" method of Array to swap each key for the desired object by picking each corresponding value from each object.

Comment: OMG, that is exactly the right result! thank you so much !
well maybe it does not give much interest, but what i was doing was:  

```
const keys = ['string', 'value'];
function mergeObjects(list) {
  return list.map((e, i) => {
    let obj = {};

    obj = { [keys[1]]: Object.values(e), [keys[2]]: Object.values(i) };
    return obj;
  });
}

const MyNewArray = mergeObjects([OBJ1, OBJ2]);
console.log('HIII', MyNewArray);
```
so my return was an array with two objects, one for all the values, and one for all de strings! 

Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
const OBJ1 = { keyNAME: "lalala", toto: "bbbb", tata: "blablabla" };

const OBJ2 = { keyNAME: 18, toto: 7, tata: null };

const createMyNewArray = (obj1, obj2) => {
  let newArray = [];

  for (const key in obj1) {
    if (key in obj2) {
      newArray.push({
        string: key,
        value: obj2[key]
      });
    }
  }
  return newArray;
};

const transformed = createMyNewArray(OBJ1, OBJ2);

console.log(transformed);
```

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-euclid-nz86lv?file=/src/index.js:299-725)